# I want to pursue studying in Social Science. What to do in summers?

Tags: computer-science, changing-fields, social-science

I am currently a second-year computer-science student. However, I am interested in pursuing social science after I am done with my bachelor's degree. To be more specific, *I am interested in the fields of Philosophy, Anthropology, and Political Science*. To be able to do that, I have started practicing and improving my writing skills. Since I do not want to continue studying CS, I will not be looking for internships or any research experience in the field.

In the summer, I want to do things that would help me getting accepted in social science. But I do not know what I can/should do. In engineering, it is pretty straightforward: It is usually an internship in a company or doing research with a prof. What are the equivalent summer positions for social science students?

Comment: 1.) What area of social science? Social science is extremely broad.
2.) I feel that the link does not contribute to your question.

Comment: I corrected it. But why the downvotes?

Comment: Because the link that you had (not anymore) could make some people think you were spamming us.

Comment: Also, you still did not include your new field of choice.

Comment: How would that be spanning when I just want to show what my fields of interests are via things I like to write about? I guess this is a bad place for consultation

Comment: If you read the FAQ’s about this stack, you will understand what types of questions should, and should not, be asked.

Comment: Internships and research seem like good choices for social science, especially given your CS background. You will get better answers if you specify which type of social science.

Comment: @cag51 I edited it. What do people in these fields do internship about though? Because when I hear the word 'internship' I can only imagine working in a company.

Comment: Social science students do internships or research in the summers as well. The focus of your internship might be different, for instance if you are interested in political economy you might look for an internship in a polling company or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation, if you really want to go into these areas and be standout, complete your computer science degree. There is a real shortage of individuals with strong computational and programming skills in the social sciences. You will likely have potential advisers salivating at the idea of having a doc student who is competent with R, especially so if you are a whiz at the ggplot2 package or tidyverse.

Learn to accentuate your skill set with a strong statistics background and you will be golden.

A strong letter of interest coupled with a strong GRE quant score and a skillset demonstrating competency in programming and statistics...this is an application that many social science faculty dream of having.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your insightful answer. But I am now curious, what would the degree that I am pursuing be in Masters, in this case? Or are you suggesting to directly get in contact with a professor and do phd?

Comment: @huzo Its probably reasonable to go straight into a PhD. Getting a masters in statistics would be a great asset for the future. Quite a few universities offer 5 year masters/bachelor's for statistics. Its a strong option if you wish to pursue academia. That said, it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to reconsider getting out of your field, there exists a "field" called complex systems (in some places), where you can combine what you know about Computer Science with social sciences, such as Economics, Anthropology and Biology.

In fact, I am an engineer who pursued a Master's degree in Applied Mathematics and I am now doing my PhD in Social Complexity, where I study social systems using ideas from anthropology.